# Kohana sorting filter implementation

Tags: php, search, filter, controller, kohana

i am trying to implement a kohana sorting filter for a virtual store, meaning that whenever i want to sort some products (after price, etc)i must only select the sorting criteria from a list. i dont want to implement the sorting in another view, so that when one chooses a sort option, he must not be redirected in another page.

so i have a list:

```
<form name="ordering" id="ordering" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="ordering" value="0">  
<select id="ordering" name="ordering">   
<option value=0>All products</option>
<option value=1>Ascending Price</option>
<option value=2>Descending price</option>


</select>
</form>
```

i want then to take that hidden value in the controller, for being able to manipulate it in the view. (is it correct?)
i need this variable in order to be able to make a switch and to determine which sorting option has been choosen by a user.

in the controller, i try to 'catch' the variable with a $ordering = $_POST['ordering']; but i receive an error, or with a

```
 if (Request::$is_post){    
    $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];         
    }
```

but it never gets there (at that bunch of code).

where i am wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [documentation of **Request** object](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#property%3amethod) and [this example](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters), you could try the following in your controller :

```
if (Request::$method == 'POST') {    
    $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];
    // ...
}
```

Note: it's recommended to put quotes around HTML tag parameters

```
<option value="0">All products</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value=0>All products</option>
```

HTH

Comment: now i get an error : Accessing static property Request::$method as non static in the controller

Comment: Aww... It seems that you have to use `Request::$method` instead of `$this->request->method`, or use directly `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` (given the Request class source code here : http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#instance) => I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

@dana: Have a look at -- http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/jquery_and_kohana_unobtrusive_ajax.php -- for an example and some direction on how to do what you wish to without having the page refresh when a user submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your HTML code, you have 3 IDs named "ordering".
I don't know how you wrote your Javascript stuff, but I wouldn't be surprised if that doesn't work, IDs should be unique.

Anyway, you say you want to get the value of the hidden field, but it doesn't have any name. So you can't access to it via PHP (unless you do it with Javascript)

According to Kohana 3.1 (the last comment was linking the 3.0 documentation), to get the value you should do the following:

```
$this->request->post('ordering');
```

What version of Kohana are you working with ?